# What event or events are fired when on appearance of alarms, reminders, or phone call notifications?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone, reminders

I'm working on a WP Silverlight game with a timer, and so need to pause the game whenever something happens to take focus away from the app. However, the PhoneApplicationService events don't fire when alarms or reminders appear on the screen, nor when phone calls arrive.

I tried overriding OnGotFocus/OnLostFocus on the page used for the game screen, but they aren't called either when a reminder/alarm dialog appears. Which brings us back to my question -- what events or overrides will let me know when alarms, reminders or calls have taken focus so I can pause my game appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the [Obscured event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - see [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/a40da829-9ea8-449f-9dc4-739a5512a493) and [this one as well](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/0572dbcb-dacf-4cf4-a803-8d95d31d5171).